# I want to zoom & center a Google map enough to fit a whole block

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, google-maps-static-api

Given an [address](https://www.google.com/maps?q=Bol%C3%ADvar%20128,%20Buenos%20Aires,%20Argentina&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=-34.609595,-58.372588&spn=0.002689,0.005284&sll=-34.609527,-58.372792&sspn=0.002689,0.005284&hnear=Bol%C3%ADvar%20128,%20Monserrat,%20Buenos%20Aires,%20Argentina&t=m&z=18), is there a way to fetch a static Google map with certain parameters in order to show the entire block including the surrounding streets?

This is the result I'm trying to achieve (I just centered and zoomed manually from Google Maps to make the screenshot):

[image: Shows the whole block]

But when requesting via Static Maps API, using zoom 17 is too far:

> [image: Not enough zoom]

and using zoom=18 is too close:

> [image: Too much zoom]

Not to mention that I can't figure out how to do the right centering of the map.

Comment: so you want to achieve it programmatically?

Comment: That's right, I guess I need to programmatically build the right URL to send to the Static Maps API.

Comment: I mean the detecting of the block(I don't think that it's possible to detect the dimension of the block programmatically)

Comment: Ok, what if I fix the zoom level at a number that I know will fit most of the blocks in my city. But still, I should somehow center the map in the middle of the block (again, the "middle" could be something that fits most cases).

Comment: What do you mean by "cases"?

Comment: I mean that I'm willing to assume a certain block dimension that matches most local cases (Buenos Aires) in order to make it easier to zoom/center the block. Say, lets say all blocks have the size as in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box way of doing this. There are plenty of possibilities for which block you want to show.

Some complications (there are more, I bet) include:

- if you're in a street corner, which of the 4 blocks should the sprite be panned to?
- if the address is a park?
- if your block has an irregular shape? *(even with the rectangular-like blocks in NYC it is complex enough due to their rotation on North axis)*

If you have the origin **latitude** and **longitude** instead of the address, you could try using the `&visible=latLng2` [argument](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#ImplicitPositioning) for the Static Maps URL, where `latLng2` is a modified version of origin including a delta (probably ~0.002 degrees) to make it look similar to your idea. This argument cannot be used with a given zoom.

**Before:**

[image: Before decentering]

**After:**

[image: After decentering]

Maybe your best option is to go with some calculations in the middle (like Google Geo services to know which is the street around the corner, etc)